Access SQL Transform and Pivot usage
I have a table below that I need to count the instances that a particular group is in a particular gate status. I'm looking for an Access SQL statement to achieve this please.  Your help is greatly appreciated!



Group
Task
Status




Group1
Task1
Gate1


Group1
Task2
Gate3


Group1
Task3
Gate3


Group1
Task4
Gate4


Group1
Task5
Gate5


Group1
Task6
Gate5


Group1
Task7
Gate5


Group2
Task1
Gate3


Group2
Task2
Gate3


Group2
Task3
Gate5


Group3
Task1
Gate4


Group3
Task1
Gate4



Need the query to show this:



Group
Gate1
Gate2
Gate3
Gate4
Gate5




Group1
1
0
2
1
3


Group2
0
0
2
0
1


Group3
0
0
0
2
0




You are missing Gate2 data in your status column, you won't be able to create a column unless you add that to your data set.  Once you get that data in there I would use a cross tab query group on the X axis and Status on the Y axis, and then for the aggregate use the ID or Task to count instances.

Depending on your groupings you may want to consider building a lookup table in MS Access.  Just creating one column in the table for all the different status that you can get in your data.  Then just left outer join into it using SQL and that would bring in all status even if your data set is missing it, as long as you set the join to left outer or all inclusive in MS Access.

To include non-exist items in column-headings (like Gate2 here), specify them in the PIVOT clause:
TRANSFORM NZ(COUNT([Task]),0) AS N
SELECT [Group]
FROM [table name]
GROUP BY [Group]
PIVOT [Status] IN ("Gate1","Gate2","Gate3","Gate4","Gate5")


Is it possible to add another column in the PIVOT that is NULL? I have some entries that are NULL and would like to count those as well. I tried adding double quotes as a column but that did not work.  PIVOT [Status] IN ("", "Gate1","Gate2","Gate3","Gate4","Gate5") did not work.

@Magicman200777, try PIVOT [Status] IN (null ,"Gate1","Gate2","Gate3","Gate4","Gate5")

you are a genius my friend!!!  Many thanks!!!  When you start out learning SQL and haven't been exposed to all the different things it can do, you don't know what you don't know so it sucks...  LOL  On top of it, you have to learn how to use this editor on this forum... :(
